# Concatenate name variable (not value) Js

Tags: javascript

My problem is simple:

I want to concatenate a dynamic variable name in a function, so with the name insert in parameter, when I call the function, she concat automatically the string in the new variable name.

**Exemple (wrong, I think):**

```
function blockDL(insertName){

    return var 'block' + insertName + 'DT'= document.createElement('dt');  

};

blockDL('First');
```

I expect the code return:

```
blockFirstDT = document.createElement('dt');
```

Thanks for your help ! =)

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Besides not being possible, I don't see a benefit doing that. You *could* use an object and store the values as properties of the object, but that seems unnecessary for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible. See ["Variable" variables in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5187530/218196) for alternatives of what you can do.

However, "variable variables" is usually a indicator of bad code design. Especially in your case, there is absolutely no reason or benefit to do any of these. Just name the variables `blockDT` and `paraphDT` or whatever you want.

Comment: I need to do this because i dont want repeat the same code for print same block, but i need to change the name of variable inside the function(it's in french):

https://openclassrooms.com/courses/dynamisez-vos-sites-web-avec-javascript/manipuler-le-code-html-partie-2-2#/id/r-1924713

Comment: No reason to practice with bad practices

Comment: @Kys3r: That's all fair and square, but if something is impossible then there is not much you can do about it. *"i dont want repeat the same code"* That's what functions are for. You define a function once and call it as often as you want. The variable names inside the function are basically irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you will be able to use a string for a variable name is by placing it as the property of another object. if you want the variable global you could use the window object.

```
window['block' + insertName + 'DT'] = document.createElement('dt');
```

that said, you really shouldn't need to and should probably look for other ways of structuring your code.

Comment: Thanks @dgeare, and now can i use the blockFirstDT outside of the function ?

Comment: @Kys3r anything defined on the window object will be a global property. so you could access it the same way from anywhere in your application. window.blockFirstDT and window["blockFirstDT"] are both proper ways of accessing the value.